# Inset triangle in a div using only css

Tags: css, css-shapes

I have been playing for a long time trying to achieve this using inset shadow css3 property. I would like to inset the blue triangle inside a div like I've seen the outside triangles done using just a border css property.

[image]

Can someone please advise me is the inset shadow approach good, or should I use some other way? How can I achieve this effect? Insetting a triangle using pure css?

Comment: "*[Please] advise me is the inset shadow approach good...*" - that depends entirely on what the 'inset shadow approach' is. Can you show us? Also, as written, this appears to be purely 'opinion based,' so may be closed unless you can refine the question.

Comment: @DavidThomas 
box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 24px blue;

Comment: @DavidThomas Thank you for your suggestion, I have edited it with a concrete question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible using `box-shadow`, however you could use a triangle on a :pseudo-element instead.

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: black;
}
div:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border-left: 50px solid transparent;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px solid #3D6AB3;
  -moz-transform: scale(0.999);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Can you please explain the why scale 0.999 property and backface visibility? Thank you.

Comment: @user2703038 - Those properties are used to make the edges smooth. If you remove them, you'll see jagged edges.  `-moz-transform: scale(0.999);` is for Firefox and `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;` is for Chrome.

Comment: How can you do this on a div which has a dynamic/unknown width?

Comment: @JonasPraem - I'd recommend  using `svg` in that case, [here's an example](https://codepen.io/chipChocolate/pen/YPNZNB?editors=1100)

Comment: I solved it by doing a `left: calc(50%-'border-left'px)` in this case 50px