# How to create a cut-out shape on the leftside of a div

Tags: html, css

I am new to css and I'm trying to create a shape on the left side of a div.

The shape I am trying to create is basically a half 45 degree angle square on the left side of the div.

Looks something like this:

[image]

What I tried, is that I used :before, and then used transform with the `skewX()` CSS function, but I couldn't get the exact shape I wanted.

Code:

```css
.square-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  margin-left: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.square-container::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -50px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  transform: skewX(-45deg);
}

.content {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="square-container">
  <div class="content">
    Test
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see I couldn't get it to budge in like it does in the picture, I can only get it to go one straight side down.

Any help would be appreciated, and I'm sorry if I formulated my question badly; I am just trying to learn.

Comment: @Jacob Updated with code

Answer (score 1):

Below is a simple example, you can adjust the specific styling to match your needs.

```css
body {
  background: #232d33;
}

.square-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #215452;
  margin-left: 50px;
  clip-path: polygon(40% 50%, 0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
}

.content {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="square-container">
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

Here is an alternative solution found in a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28012913/inset-triangle-in-a-div-using-only-css) provided by *Roy* and adjusted slightly to fit your requirement (the triangle on the left side, rather than the bottom).

```css
body {
  background: #232d33;
}

div {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #215452;
}

div:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-top: 50px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
  border-right: 40px solid #232d33;
  transform: scaleX(-1);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```